# How to develop pivot table in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy, spreadsheet, pivot-table

I am developing a tool that is to replace a rather large Excel Workbook and I am trying to minimise the development effort. In order to do so - I am looking for Java Components that do similar things to what excel does.

The primary functionality that I am looking to implement is the following:

1. A table that can be easily exported to Excel
2. Provides the Pivot Table functionality (as in Excel)
3. Provides the general table functionality like - filtering, sorting, copy & paste
4. Is something that has a real professional look and the look & feel can be customised.

Can i use Spring Rich Client to do the same thing.

Is there any plugin or inbuilt support to develop pivot table in groovy/grails

Comment: does this meet ur need http://oswing.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider

- http://www.jidesoft.com/products/pivot.htm
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagallanes/

Comment: Jidesoft is not open source project, I am looking for open source projects

Answer (score 0):

As javascript becomes more and more powerful and many MVC logics moved from back end side (java) to front end side(javascript). Browsers becomes an application platform now. So a pure javascript pivot table implementation might be a better choice.

[Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is pure javascript pivot table implementation which provides all functions just like excel pivot table and you can easily embed it into any web application, no matter what kinds of technology you are using at back end. Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).